# How to join two file with single columns values separated by comma in perl

Tags: perl, join

I have two files.

file1  contains

```
abc
def
ghi
```

in a single column (3 separate lines)

file2 contains

```
123
456
789
```

(in single column (3 separate  lines)

I am trying to join the values from these two files into a new comma separated file. I was hoping to capture all the values from one file into two different arrays and use the 'join' command to 'join' them. But I am running into several errors while trying to capture the values into the arrays. I tried several while loops. But all of them kept running into one error or the other. Here is the latest while loop I have

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename1 = "file1";
open ( my $fh , "<", $filename1) or die "Could not open '$filename1'\n";
while (1) {my $line = <$fh>} ;
my @name = $line ;
print @name;
```

I know I should be able to do this with a simple 'join' command using bash. But I want to learn how to do this in perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the number of lines of file1 is the same with file2.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open (my $IN1,'<','file1.txt') or die "$!"; #open 1st file
open (my $IN2,'<','file2.txt') or die "$!"; #open 2nd file
open (my $OUT,'>','out.txt') or die "$!";   #create new file
while (<$IN1>) {
    chomp;                                  #remove newline from each row of the 1st file
    my $x=readline $IN2;                    #read line from 2nd file
    print $OUT join(',',$_,$x);             #print the desired output
}
close $IN1;
close $IN2;
close $OUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, you want the output

```
abc,123
def,456
ghi,789
```

for the example you gave, right?
If so, the following code should do the thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open F1, "file1.in" or die "$!";
open F2, "file2.in" or die "$!";
open OUTPUT_FILE, ">output.out" or die "$!";

while (defined(my $f1 = <F1>) and defined(my $f2 = <F2>)) {
    chomp $f1;
    chomp $f2;
    print OUTPUT_FILE "$f1,$f2\n";
}

close OUTPUT_FILE;
close F1;
close F2;
```

Answer (score 0):

join in bash does something different than join in Perl.  In Perl, you will need to use a loop, or something like List::MoreUtils::pairwise or Algorithms::Loops::MapCar.

```
use File::Slurp 'read_file';
my @file1_lines = read_file('file1', 'chomp' => 1);
my @file2_lines = read_file('file2');
```

then:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'pairwise'; use vars qw/$a $b/;
print pairwise { "$a,$b" } @file1_lines, @file2_lines;
```

or:

```
use Algorithm::Loops 'MapCarE';
print MapCarE { "$_[0],$_[1]" } \@file1_lines, \@file2_lines;
```

(MapCarE throws an exception if the files have different numbers of lines; other variants have other behaviors.)

Comment: Sorry I am not advanced enough to use modules yet. I am still getting my feet wet with Perl. But I will put these modules you mentioned in my notes so when I  get to the modules I can pay extra attention to those.

Comment: when you are getting your feet wet is the best time.  perl is all about using modules.